# How to instrument a C# .NET Core Console App with vsinstr?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, code-coverage

I am trying to instrument a dll built in Visual Studio 2017. All I did was create a Visual C# project and choose "Console App (.NET Core)", then build the default hello world program. DLL and PDB files are generated in the bin Release folder but when I try to instrument the DLL with [vsinstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/vsinstr?view=vs-2017) I get hit with error VSP1030: Invalid, mismatched, or no PDB file was found

As you can see the dll file is clearly present, so i'm wondering if there is some project setting that I need to enable, or if i'm not using the visual studio profiling tools as intended. With a C++ project I just had to turn on the /Profile flag in linker options, but there seems to be no similar setting for this project.
[image: Release folder]

Comment: open cmd got to path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64` then write  vsinstr.exe [YourPath]\[dll]

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work even if i run vsinstr.exe directly from that folder on my dll, it gives me the same error. I then tried it without the /coverage flag like you suggested but it just gives me a different VSP1033 "The file does not contain a recognized executable image" error instead.